# TOC/bookmark not accurate when containing math content (Something weird at ToC and math mode)

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I put at one of my sections this: `$\left\langle a,b\right\rangle $` and what I get is something very wired!
[image]

Do you know why it's happens and I can I solve it? If there is a solution for it...

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\section{ABC $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle $}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Suggest changing title of question.  "Wired" is colloquial, not necessarily understood by international audience of this site.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes can you suggest me other word please?

Comment: "TOC/bookmark not accurate when containing math content", for example.

Comment: Or maybe you just meant "weird" instead of "wired"?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I change it! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math mode stuff is not allowed in a bookmark.  You should use `\texorpdfstring{stuff in document}{stuff in bookmark>`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\section{ABC \texorpdfstring{$\left\langle a,b\right\rangle $}{<a,b>}}

\end{document}
```

[image]